Exported SVGs plots fonts twice
I'm using Blender to plot patterns with the Freestyle SVG export and SignCut Pro for plotting.
It works great for lines, but it always traces over any text twice.
I've tried using single-line fonts, but it still plots the font fully and then traces over it again.
Opening the SVG file in Inkscape and deleting the extra lines over the text does solve the issue, but it takes about as much time as letting it plot twice anyway.
Has anyone come across this problem before, and is there a setting in Blender to correct this behavior?

What is SignCutPro?

It's cutting and plotting software.  It takes an svg and allows you to print it out on a plotter

In that case, why are you using Blender as an SVG maker when you have Inkscape?

I'm unwrapping a 3d model in blender and generating the svg there

So… Are you trying to irl cut out the shape that will fold back into the model?

Yes exactly!  I have numbered each piece in blender using text.  Then I render the pieces using an orthographic camera and freestyle svg export. This gives me an svg I can print using signcut but, the text vector always plots twice.
